# Why do Visual Studio and Task Manager report different memory usages?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a program in Visual Studio which I'm debugging. It's designed to test the memory of a computer (and conveniently named `RAM`...).

While debugging, the amount of memory usage from that program goes up continually. Anyway, I've used the Visual Studio diagnostic tools to monitor the amount of usage. Only recently, however, have I opened up Task Manager to see it in detail; and what I saw confused me. The amount of RAM usage is **significantly** less than what the diagnostic tools say.

[image: Task Manager and Diagnostic Tools]

Can anyone tell me as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this can be a bit late but I just encountered the same problem and [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79ce4470-47ab-403a-a415-69b9f332bc0d/vs-2017-performance-profiler-vs-task-manager?forum=vsdebug) provided a bit of explanation. It seems that Task Manager displays the working set (amount of memory you use) and the Diagnostic tools from VS displays virtual memory used for storage and not shared.

I guess you found your answer but maybe others will stumble on this too and this might be helpful. Cheers! :)